# How to deal with an unknown power switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, walls

My wife and I recently moved into a new home. There is a room which we understand the former owner used as a private doctor's practice. As such in one corner of the room, there is some telecoms equipment for a business/commercial digital telephone line. Near to this equipment, there is a switch on the wall for which we cannot determine the function.

I am intending to remove the telephone equipment from the wall, as we will be redecorating the room. However, I'd also like to remove the switch, but unsure how to determine what it does. If you switch it on, a red light on the switch comes on which indicates there is power there, but what it is switching on isn't clear. Can't see anything happening when I turn switch on other than this red light built into the switch itself.

It proximity to the telephone equipment makes me wonder if it's related, but it is also just far enough away that it is conceivable that it might not be anything to do with that.

Is there any way of determining what the switch does? Perhaps a way of tracing the wires in the wall to see where they go?

Additionally, if we determine the switch can be safely removed, with what would we fill in the hole left behind?

Comment: You're asking several very different questions up there. Please ask just one, and provide enough information for us to help. We don't even know what your wall is made of.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/58902/how-can-i-trace-the-wires-of-a-circuit

Comment: Or this? https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/125838/is-it-possible-to-trace-a-wire-to-a-breaker-if-you-dont-have-access-to-the-inne

Comment: Usually a switch will turn on/off a light or an outlet, hopefully in the same room.  A simple desk lamp can be used for the outlets, test top and bottom.  For lights need to make sure the bulbs are working first.  If nothing works in that room, need to check other rooms/hallways near by and closets.

Comment: Please take a photograph of the switch with the red light showing (and the switch plate removed), and add it to your post via an edit.

Comment: If it used to be a doctor's office, perhaps it was a switch for a call light to request a nurse or other assistant from another part of the house?  Or check all of the outlets in the room to see if any of them might be controlled by the switch.  Perhaps the lighted switch was installed as an indicator to the doctor that some piece of equipment was energized for safety reasons?  But without further information, it'll likely end up requiring some detective work on your part.

Comment: Also, you could ask (perhaps through your realtor) the previous owner, what it was for.  Hopefully they wouldn't mind answering a simple question like that.